# Visio VBA filling hyperlinked boxes

Tags: vba, hyperlink, visio

I am fairly proficient in VBA when it comes to excel, but not so much in Visio.  What I want to do is simple.  If I had a hyperlink to an object, I want that object to be filled with the color blue.  In excel, I could do this no problem.  In Visio, not so much.  The flowchart is simple enough, I would say 20 objects or so and not all of them will be hyperlinked.

Comment: I tangled with Visio a bit at a previous gig. While I unfortunately don't have access to an install to play around with, a few minutes on the MSDN site turned up a couple interesting links: 1. the `Shape.Hyperlinks` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768171(v=office.15).aspx) and 2. the `Hyperlink.Address` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765684(v=office.15).aspx). Perhaps you could iterate through the shapes, checking to see if `Hyperlink.Address` is empty, using that as the `If...Then` check to apply color changes?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the edit and the down vote.  It's my first question on here, and I just needed a little help.

Dan, thanks for your reply.  I know I am close to getting it to work, but I am just too unfamiliar with the syntax used in Visio.  I will have to keep looking around and hope to find something.

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter

Comment: No no I know. This Visio code is so frustrating because I know it is so simple, but I just don't know anything about Visio VBA syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some VBA psuedo-code that I might try in the vein of my comment above:

```
Dim Sh As Visio.Shape
Dim Link As Hyperlink

For Each Sh In Visio.ActivePage.Shapes  '<~ loop through the shapes collection
    For Each Link In Sh.Hyperlinks      '<~ loop through the links collection
        If Not Link.Address = "" Then   '<~ check for a blank address
            Sh.Cells("Fillforegnd") = 2 '<~ apply a color to the shape
        End If
    Next Link
Next Sh
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that worked perfectly.  Next thing I have to figure out is how to get the page to implement those changes without the use of a button.  Usually in excel I just use the Workbook_Change sub, but I will have to play around with it.  Thanks again.

Comment: now I am looking to add to your code.  I am trying to add to the code so it will change to another color if the hyperlink address is empty.  This is what I tried:

Set Sh = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(1)
 For Each Link In Sh.Hyperlinks
    If Link.Address <> "" Then
    Sh.Cells("Fillforegnd").Formula = "RGB(255, 102, 0)"
    ElseIf Link.Address = " " Then
    Sh.Cells("Fillforegnd") = 1
    End If
Next Link
    
    
End Sub

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request... Did your attempt not work? I would keeping all but the most simple code snippets out of comments, better to edit the original post if it's a small adjustment or ask a new question if it's a large adjustment